# How to create NSPopover programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nspopover

i've didn't found some examples to create NSPopover dynamically instead using the Interface Builder.

Following code gives an exception, loaded nib, but no view is set:

```
NSViewController *controller = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View"     bundle:nil];
NSPopover *popover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[popover setContentSize:NSMakeSize(100.0f, 100.0f)];
[popover setContentViewController:controller];
[popover setAnimates:YES];
[popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
[popover release];
[controller release];
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
2011-10-22 12:00:16.804 Test[2020:707] -[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "View" nib    but no view was set.
2011-10-22 12:00:16.807 Test[2020:707] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87e10286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff92f2cd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87e100ba +[NSException   raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87e10044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff90951e21 -[NSViewController loadView] + 336
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9094da8a -[NSViewController view] + 41
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff91065232 -[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:] + 159
7   Test                                0x000000010000159a -[OITAppDelegate show:] + 570
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87dffa1d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff90924710 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924642 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9092456d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff90923a30 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff909a38e0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff9092263a -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff908ed0e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9088568f -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff9081b682 -[NSApplication run] + 555
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a9a80c NSApplicationMain + 867
19  Test                                0x00000001000012f2 main + 34
20  Test                                0x00000001000012c4 start + 52
21  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is not in NSPopover; the exception is thrown by NSViewController, and it says that although nib load was successful, it's `view` property is still `nil`.

Open “View.nib” in Interface Builder and assign *File Owner*'s `view` outlet to the view object that the controller is supposed to represent (NSViewContoller becomes the file owner when it loads a nib). This is done by Ctrl-dragging from File Owner icon to the view's icon, then choosing `view` from the list of outlets.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer to this old question.  A related question: how did you know that this exception related to failing to assign the *view* outlet, as opposed to something else -- say, failing to assign the popover’s *contentViewController* outlet?

Comment: @MarkBernstein This exception with this message text is only raised when loading did not assign the `view` property.